# Image is not loaded from url

Tags: android, image, url, imageview

In my app, I have to show image in image view from url. The web service is giving complete listings with all information related to the them. I am storing all information into a data access object and pass that to detail page. On my detail page,I have to show image from the url that I got from the webservice. But, the image does not shows up. Below is my code:

**Image Loader**

```
public class ImageLoader {

public static final String TAG = "ImageLoaderSN";
public enum BitmapManager {
    INSTANCE;

    private final Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache;
    private final ExecutorService pool;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    private Bitmap placeholder;

    BitmapManager() {
        cache = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public void setPlaceholder(Bitmap bmp) {
        placeholder = bmp;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromCache(String url) 
    {
        //Log.v(TAG, "getBitmapFromCache called");
        if (cache.containsKey(url)) 
        {
            //Log.v(TAG, "getBitmapFromCache if loop");
            return cache.get(url).get();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void queueJob(final String url, final ImageView imageView,
            final int width, final int height) 
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "queueJob called");
        //Create handler in UI thread. 
        final Handler handler = new Handler() 
        {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
            {
                //Log.v(TAG, "queueJob handleMessage called");
                String tag = imageViews.get(imageView);
                if (tag != null && tag.equals(url)) 
                {
                    //Log.v(TAG, "queueJob tag not null");
                    if (msg.obj != null) 
                    {
                        //Log.v(TAG, "queueJob msg.obj not null");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) msg.obj);
                    } else 
                    {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(placeholder);
                        //Log.v(TAG, "queueJob fail " + url);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        pool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final Bitmap bmp = downloadBitmap(url, width, height);
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.obj = bmp;
                //Log.d(null, "Item downloaded: " + url);

                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadBitmap(String url, final ImageView imageView,
            final int width, final int height) 
    {
        //Log.v(TAG, "loadBitmap called");
        if(url.contains(" "))
        {
            //Log.v(TAG, "if url contains spaces");
          url  = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        }
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(url);

        // check in UI thread, so no concurrency issues
        if (bitmap != null) 
        {
            //Log.v(TAG, "Item loaded from cache: " + url);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } 
        else 
        {
            //Log.v(TAG, "else loadBitmap");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(placeholder);
            queueJob(url, imageView, width, height);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url, int width, int height) {
        try {

             String URL  = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                    URL).getContent());


            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
            cache.put(URL, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
            return bitmap;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

     public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth) {

            int width = bm.getWidth();

            int height = bm.getHeight();

        float aspect = (float)width / height;

        float scaleWidth = newWidth;

        float scaleHeight = scaleWidth / aspect;        // yeah!

        // create a matrix for the manipulation

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        // resize the bit map

        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth / width, scaleHeight / height);

        // recreate the new Bitmap

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

            bm.recycle();

            return resizedBitmap;
        }

}

}
```

Upon checking, I found that image url was not null. But, handler in the queueJob() in ImageLoader class didn't run, when there was no bitmap in the cache. I tested the same code independently, and it worked. Can't find out what is actual problem.

Comment: are you getting any errors or exception.? check your manifest file for required permissions. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and INTERNET Permission is required for the above to work.

Comment: There is no need of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as I am not saving image on SD card. The image's bitmap gets stored in cache. If the bitmap is not present in the cache then, it will fetch bitmap from url which will be done by queueJob() in the ImageLoader. The problem is when there is no bitmap in the cache,the handler in the queueJob() never gets called up, as I have mentioned above. However, INTERNET permission is already there in my manifest.